# Default view to 'All activities' on Account form

Tags: dynamics-crm, formview

On Accounts form in MS dynamics crm online, have a related view of Activities as shown below.

[image: (as show in pic1)]

Now, I have updated default view of above to 'All activities' but once you 'Related records' (circled green) then it opens up another view in an iframe (as shown here). I want to default this view to 'All Activities' so that the user would be able to see all the activities of that particular record and of the related records in one click.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the columns shown in the Associated View itself, but you cannot change the default view that is shown when clicking the button you highlighted in green: *See the records associated with this view*.

There is a suggestion on Connect in regards to being able to change the default filters on the Activity Associated View: [Ability to default related Activities "Filter on" to All](https://connect.microsoft.com/dynamicssuggestions/feedback/details/2031533/ability-to-default-related-activities-filter-on-to-all)

Comment: Link that you provided is broken. :-(

Comment: Broken how? Connect sometimes has issues if you are already logged in to your Microsoft account. Does it work in incognito?

Comment: * coff coff * http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/02/how-to-use-microsoft-connect-site.html